# Why my browser give me a syntax error about a div?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state, react-fragment

Browser give me this error [image] What I'm doing wrong? This appeared only when I added the code for the loader

```
    function App(){
     const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
        
        useEffect(() => {
          setLoading(true)
          setTimeout(() => {
            setLoading(false)
          }, 5000)
        }, [])
        
        
          return (
            <div className="App">
        {
                loading ? 
                <img src={loader} alt=""
                loading={loading}
                />
              :
         //all my code
     
    }
     </div>
)}
```

Comment: Can you provide complete code in else condition of loading?

Comment: There can only be one parent element in the JSX that's in the return. Enclose it in Fragment if there are multiple elements. That means you can't have `return (<App></App><div>whatever</div>` - it has to be all one parent like `return (<App><div></div></App>`